# read code 39 barcode with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, zxing

My goal with this project is to create a windows form application using VB.net to read a barcode from an image (form a file for now, taken with a webcam later) and write the text to a textbox.  I've found plenty of examples of how to decode bar codes using the Zxing library for pretty much every language except vb.net.  I have an image which contains a code 39 (I believe) bar code.

[image]

After adding a reference to Zxing.dll and importing the desired namespace, I have this:

```
Imports ZXing.OneD
Public Class Form2
    Private webcam As WebCam
    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        webcam = New WebCam()
        webcam.InitializeWebCam(imgVideo)
        webcam.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        imgCapture.Image = imgVideo.Image 'I plan to use this later


        Dim reader As New ZXing.OneD.Code39Reader
        Dim image1 As Bitmap
        image1 = Image.FromFile("C:\Capture.jpg") 'this is the image I'm using for testing purposes

        reader.decode(image1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

the line `reader.decode(image1)` generates an error:

```
"Error  1   Value of type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' cannot be converted to 'ZXing.BinaryBitmap'"
```

Clearly, I'm dabbling with things I don't yet understand... so I'm begging for help!  I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Express.

I've changed it yet again.  this code generates no error, yet it returns nothing.

```
Imports ZXing
Imports ZXing.OneD
Public Class Form2
    Private webcam As WebCam
    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        webcam = New WebCam()
        webcam.InitializeWebCam(imgVideo)
        webcam.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        imgCapture.Image = imgVideo.Image 'I plan to use this later

        Dim reader As Code39Reader = New Code39Reader
        Dim image1 As Bitmap = New Bitmap("C:\Capture.bmp")
        Dim bitmapBytes As Byte()
        Using stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
            image1.Save(stream, image1.RawFormat)
            bitmapBytes = stream.GetBuffer
        End Using
        Dim Lumin As LuminanceSource = New RGBLuminanceSource(bitmapBytes, image1.Width, image1.Height, bitmapFormat:=RGBLuminanceSource.BitmapFormat.RGB24)

        Dim HBin As Common.HybridBinarizer = New Common.HybridBinarizer(Lumin)
        Dim Bitm As BinaryBitmap = New BinaryBitmap(HBin)
        Dim res As String = reader.decode(Bitm).Text
    End Sub
End Class
```

**EDIT***
This is the working solution.  Thanks for the help guys!

```
Imports ZXing
Imports ZXing.OneD
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form2
    Private webcam As WebCam
    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        webcam = New WebCam()
        webcam.InitializeWebCam(imgVideo)
        webcam.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        imgCapture.Image = imgVideo.Image 'I plan to use this later
        Dim reader As New ZXing.BarcodeReader
        Dim image1 As Bitmap
        image1 = Image.FromFile("C:\Capture.bmp")
        Dim res As Result = reader.Decode(image1)
        MsgBox(res.Text)
    End Sub

    Public Function GetRGBValues(ByVal Bmp As Bitmap) As Byte()
        Dim Rect As New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height)
        Dim BmpData As System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData = Bmp.LockBits(Rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, Bmp.PixelFormat)
        Dim Ptr As IntPtr = BmpData.Scan0
        Dim Bytes As Integer = BmpData.Stride * Bmp.Height
        Dim RgbValues As Byte() = New Byte(Bytes - 1) {}
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(Ptr, RgbValues, 0, Bytes)
        Bmp.UnlockBits(BmpData)
        Return RgbValues
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: It's simple. `reader.decode()` takes a parameter of type `ZXing.BinaryBitmap`, but you try to feed it a parameter of type `System.Drawing.Bitmap`. So somehow you must find a way to create a `ZXing.BinaryBitmap` from a normal `Bitmap`.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/441372/zxing-QRCode-Encoding-and-Decoding-in-csharp) could help you?

Comment: @Visual Vincent -I've edited the code (and my question) based on the example you provided, but still no joy

Comment: It wants a 1-dimensional array of what??

Comment: heck if I know, error says "Value of type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Byte'."

Comment: Then it clearly states that it wants a 1-dimensional array of **Byte**. You need to be specific when writing error messages. You can have a one dimensional array of pretty much anything.

Comment: It's like saying _"Hey, I need a 3m long."_ -Well, 3m long what?

Comment: Well now that we now what the problem is we can start looking for solutions. The `RGBLuminanceSource` class/structure needs an image in the form of an array of bytes.

Comment: I've posted an answer, if the first function does not work, maybe the second one will?

Comment: 3of9 expects a start and stop code... add an asterisk `*` to the beginning and end of each of your strings you are rendering barcodes for.  Without these chacters you will not have valid barcodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with the barcodes you are trying to read.  Not with how you are trying to read them.  You need start and stop characters on [code 39](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_39#Encoding).  Add an asterisk `*` to the beginning and end of each string you are rendering barcodes for.  Without these characters your barcodes are invalid and can not be read.

Comment: Ah, so you mean like `*THIS IS BARCODE*`?

Comment: Yes... but it looks like your library isn't encoding the spaces either.  There should be no gaps in the finished barcode.

Comment: Don't talk to me, talk to user3479671. :)

Comment: lol... sorry, I thought you were OP :) ... I didn't read the name I just replied to your comment.

Comment: it's ok, i'm paying attention.  I changed the image to a bar code that read *effingwork*, but it still returns nothing

Comment: @user3479671 You should use the ` character around the text you want to escape, `like so`.

Comment: Did you try `*effingwork*`?  Go grab the sample barcode on wikipedia and see if your code reads that.

Comment: He tried it, but when putting * around a word on StackOverflow it becomes *italics* if not `escaped`.

Comment: yeah... I see that now :) ... I'd suggest OP tries a known good barcode instead of fighting two problems at once.

Comment: the wikepedia one works! so what's wrong with my bar code?  It's generated using IDAutomationHC39M.  based on the name, I thought it to be code 39

Comment: @user3479671 : `IDAutomationHC39M` is a font. There's no guarantee that it will be accurate enough. And also as Matthew said, there should probably not be any spaces. Try generating one from this site and see if that works: http://generator.barcoding.com/

Comment: What application or framework are you using to make the barcode?  If you are using a wordprocessor or even a graphics tool it might be messing with the sizing/spacing of the characters.

Comment: Ok, I switched the reader from Code39Reader to BarcodeReader.  Looks like the spaces and asterisks were the problem from the beginning.

Comment: great... if you have more problems try increasing your fontsize a little as it will give the reader a little more fudge factor on reading the code.

Answer (score 3):

So the `RGBLuminanceSource` requires a byte array in it's constructor.

I cannot seem to find a proper documentation for this, but this will convert an `Image` to an array of `Bytes`:

```
Public Function ImageToByteArray(ByVal Img As Image) As Byte()
    Using ms As New MemoryStream
        Img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        Return ms.ToArray()
    End Using
End Function
```

Example call:

```
Dim Lumin As New ZXing.RGBLuminanceSource(ImageToByteArray(image1), image1.Width, image1.Height)
```

---

If the above does not work there's also this function which will take only the image's pixels (I'm not sure if the above takes more than just the pixels):

```
Public Function GetRGBValues(ByVal Bmp As Bitmap) As Byte()
    Dim Rect As New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height)
    Dim BmpData As System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData = Bmp.LockBits(Rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, Bmp.PixelFormat)

    Dim Ptr As IntPtr = BmpData.Scan0

    Dim Bytes As Integer = BmpData.Stride * Bmp.Height
    Dim RgbValues As Byte() = New Byte(Bytes - 1) {}

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(Ptr, RgbValues, 0, Bytes)
    Bmp.UnlockBits(BmpData)

    Return RgbValues
End Function
```

Comment: it executes without error using GetRGBValues, but after the line "Dim res As Result = reader.decode(Bitm)", the res variable returns nothing

Comment: @user3479671 : Well then I'm sorry to say that I don't think there's anything more I can do. I've never used this library or anything like this, and I don't have any more ideas.

Comment: thanks for your efforts.  If this does lead to a soution, then I'll be sure to accept it as the answer.

Comment: @user3479671 : I'm more certain that Matthew's answer will, but thanks. :)